# Processing 4.0b9 profileImpl GL3bc !!! not mapped

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 
Graphic card: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics (HSW GT1) 
Processing 4.0b9 give this error:

```
java.lang.InternalError: XXX0 profile[2]: GL2 -> profileImpl GL3bc !!! not mapped 
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.computeProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2098)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDeviceCritical(GLProfile.java:1976)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDevice(GLProfile.java:1895)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1861)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:80)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:239)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:225)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2324)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1009)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getGL2ES2(GLProfile.java:930)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initGL(PSurfaceJOGL.java:215)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initFrame(PSurfaceJOGL.java:149)
    at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10542)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10448)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10187)
InternalError: XXX0 profile[2]: GL2 -> profileImpl GL3bc !!! not mapped
```

Everything was working before the ubuntu update.

Upd: Now error was changed

```
java.lang.InternalError: XXX0 profile[2]: GL2 -> profileImpl GL3bc !!! not mapped 
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.computeProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2098)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDeviceCritical(GLProfile.java:1976)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDevice(GLProfile.java:1895)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1861)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:80)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:239)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:225)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2324)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1009)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getGL2ES2(GLProfile.java:930)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initGL(PSurfaceJOGL.java:215)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initFrame(PSurfaceJOGL.java:149)
    at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10537)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10443)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10187)
    at MPUTeapot.main(MPUTeapot.java:210)
X11Util.Display: Shutdown (JVM shutdown: true, open (no close attempt): 1/1, reusable (open, marked uncloseable): 0, pending (open in creation order): 1)
X11Util: Open X11 Display Connections: 1
X11Util: Open[0]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x7f61f80019d0, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
```

Comment: You can ask this on the [Linux Stack Site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) -- The [Ubuntu Stack Site](https://askubuntu.com/) or even [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) --  Any of them this question will be more relevant on.

Comment: Possible known bug: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434264/profileimpl-gl4bc-not-mapped